# Jenkins build flow and parameterized downstream projects

Tags: jenkins

We are using Jenkins and the build-flow plugin to orchestrate some jobs for our deployment. After the build-flow finished, we want to trigger some more jobs as a downstream dependency.

I tried to solve this requirement via a post-build action, where I set up a trigger for parameterized builds on other projects. It should be triggered when the flow is "stable or unstable but not failed", but the build-flow job refuses to trigger any of these downstream jobs although the current build was green and also the last five builds where green, so the build-flow is stable.

Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem or did I just found a bug in the build-flow plugin? Google didn’t show me any helpful results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have exactly the same issue.
Jenkins ver. 1.601 with CloudBees Build Flow plugin 0.17

Workaround: enable "Flow run needs a workspace"

Seems as [known issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22779)

Comment: “While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.”

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to a [problem I had](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27180327/downstream-jenkins-project-gets-wrong-upstream-run-parameter). The solution was to *not* filter the run parameter in the configuration of the downstream job.

Comment: I guess, we are not using the some plugin. Our configuration looks like this:

[Build flow](http://www2.caldera.cc/build-flow.png)