# How to send email with Jenkins and an parameter address?

Tags: email, plugins, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins and I would like to send an email after finished job. The problem I have is that I want to use the username defined before into a parameter in the configuration. I try to use then ${username} but i doesn't work. This is the error I get:

```
Sending e-mails to: ${username}@email.es
ERROR: Invalid Addresses
javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
nested exception is:
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 5.1.1 <${username}@email.es>... User unknown

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1835)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1098)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at hudson.tasks.MailSender.run(MailSender.java:126)
at hudson.tasks.MailSender.execute(MailSender.java:101)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.cleanUp(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1064)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1764)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:531)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 5.1.1 <${username}@email.es>... User unknown

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1686)
... 10 more
```

It is not taking the value of the parameter. Is thera any plugin or way to do this ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is your parameter defined under the config section "This build is parameterised"? Of what type is it?

Comment: I put it 'cadena' in spanish. I think is String Parameter. And yes,it is under check 'This build is parameterized'. I have another String parameter to use the SVN url and this it works fine. The problem is with the email in the Properties of the proyect --> Email Notification.

Comment: Strange, I've tried it and it works for me. What is your version of Jenkins?

Comment: My version is Jenkins ver. 1.599. The parameter arrives from another task invocation with groovy script. I have two parameters, and the SVN parameter I used to compile the code inside, and the username parameter I used to send email, but the console give me the error.

Comment: Ok, I tried to do it in the first job, and it works, but when I propagate the job params to the next job to run, then it doesn't work.

Comment: Does this look like the same issue? http://stackoverflow.com/q/27180327/1464763

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I 'found' the solution. With a maven project, it doesn' work with the simply Email notification inside the Build properties. I must use a plugin 'Ext-mail plugin' to do it. Thanks for all.

Answer (score 1):

instead of ${username} - use $username

Ex: $username@$domain.com

Here, username and domain are two parameters for build 
(defined by selecting checkbox-This build is parameterized)

Comment: Keep going the same error. I put in the parameters 'author' with a value, and then in the input fieldo for the email: '$author@prueba.es ' and the error is shown.

Comment: I updated the log error. The email is an example there, no the real domain.

Answer (score 1):

Configure Jenkins System for Email Notifications

To do this:

"Jenkins Dashboard -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System"

At the bottom of the page- find : Email Notification

Then give email notification details

**I have configured like this:**

**SMTP server** : smtp.gmail.com

**Default user e-mail suffix** : @gmail.com

select checkbox USE smtp authentication

give: **username** (without @gmail.com) -eg: enter mike for mike@gmail.com

give your **password**

Select checkbox Use SSL

**SMTP port** : 465

try your email settings by sending a test mail

If your able to send it successfuly. its done

/* In the Build - The Build is Parameterized */

1st parameter

**Name** : username
**Default Value** : mike

2nd Parameter

**Name**: domain
**Default Value**: gmail

//Post-Build Actions - **Email Notification**
(able to see this only when you have Mailer plugin installed)

**Recipients** : $username@$domain.com

This should work ..

Comment: I already have the configuration well-set. Thanks for you explanation. The problem is other, I can't send an email because the param it's not well filtered ($user). I think it's because of I run the job trigger by another job that propagate the param I used to send the email.